# axios response.data is empty

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, axios

I am implementing React-Redux. 
following is in my actions file

```
const fetchCustomers = () => {
  return (dispatch) => {
    axios
      .get('/api/customers')
      .then((response) => { 
        console.log('List of all Customers - ',response)
        dispatch({ type: FETCH_CUSTOMERS, payload: response.data }) 
      })
  }
};
```

I am calling the actions creator as follows:

```
store.dispatch(fetchCustomers());
```

A console.log int api just before responding back shows the correct data:

```
[0] [ { customerRequest: [ [Object] ],
[0]     _id: 5c82a0444713453b9472038d,
[0]     name: 'user4',
[0]     mobile: '84357984375',
[0]     updated: 2019-03-08T17:03:19.360Z,
[0]     created: 2019-03-08T17:03:00.462Z,
[0]     createdBy: 'Avinash Shetty',
[0]     customerId: 87,
[0]     __v: 1,
[0]     updatedBy: 'Avinash Shetty' },
[0]   { customerRequest: [ [Object] ],
[0]     _id: 5c81a86afe50590ae86ee2d2,
[0]     name: 'user3',
[0]     mobile: '348753456',
[0]     updated: 2019-03-07T23:26:45.676Z,
[0]     created: 2019-03-07T23:25:30.173Z,
[0]     createdBy: 'Avinash Shetty',
[0]     customerId: 86,
[0]     __v: 1,
[0]     updatedBy: 'Avinash Shetty' },
```

The above code was working fine but suddenly it has stopped getting the data.
A Console.log in the then clause of axios.get returns

```
config: {adapter: ƒ, transformRequest: {…}, transformResponse: {…}, timeout: 0, xsrfCookieName: "XSRF-TOKEN", …}
data: ""
headers: {strict-transport-security: "max-age=15552000; includeSubDomains", content-encoding: "gzip", x-content-type-options: "nosniff", access-control-allow-origin: "*", x-powered-by: "Express", …}
request: XMLHttpRequest {onreadystatechange: ƒ, readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, upload: XMLHttpRequestUpload, …}
status: 200
statusText: ""
__proto__: Object
```

There code was working fine for the last 2 months. I have also demonstrated to the client. Suddenly, for some reason it does not get the returning data now. Once it errors, whatever attempts I do, it does not start fetching again.

Please guide, what can be the issue here.

Comment: I found that, if I insert a customer, the code works again. does not fail. however, if I clear the browser cache... it fails again. My addCustomer page calls the fetchCustomers after a successful insert. So when I call from addCustomer it works. But when I call fetchCustomers from within the store at initialization time, it does not work.... weird. please help.